# Informatica PowerExchange CDC Data results in target DB way too slow

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, cdc, informatica-powerexchange

First of all, I'm very new to Informatica PowerCenter and PowerExchange.

We are using Informatica PowerCenter and PowerExchange to receive CDC data from our source DB2 to a PostgreSQL DB. Therefore we have one workflow where 7 tables are mapped and we get the result in our PostgreSQL. It works fine so far, but it's lacking performance. Not that the size of data is the problem, it's more the delay I see results in the target DB.

When I insert or delete some data on the DB2 (just like 10 rows in one db), I see the results in our PostgreSQL mostly in about ~10-30 seconds (very rare in less than 5 seconds).

My goal would be to speed up this delay. Is this possible? What would I need for that? 
I played a little bit with commit interval, and DTM Buffer size, but nothing helped pretty much. 
Also I have the feeling that when I configure the workflow to run continuously, it's even slower, compared to when I execute the workflow, after I made the Inserts/Deletes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the session log?

Comment: Yeah agree we need the log, also you haven't mentioned what networking there is between the source db and the powerexchange server. Naturally the less networking in the solution the fewer lags you'll see

Comment: Hi together, I've checked the logs and I don't think the logs will help. From the logs I can see that the job itself is running ~6 seconds. Then the log isn't even touched for like 40-60 seconds, so I think the workflow isn't directly running again after it has finished. There is some pause or similar I think. Or does continuously workflow schedule mean, that it also runs just every minute, and only repetitive. If you still think the SessLog can help, I will add it. Thanks!